# JavaScript stops at ToString

Tags: javascript, scorm

Question for JavaScript experts out there. I have a SCORM (e-learning content package) which is failing at a very specific point in the JavaScript. I have set up logging to see where it is failing and it is actually failing at one of my logs so its as if converting the object to a string is causing a problem. Am I missing something here?

```
var w = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
var $w = $(w.document.body);

function writelog(s){
    $w.append(s);
}


function SCOSetValue(nam,val){
    writelog("in SCOSetValue");
    writelog("name is "+nam.toString());
    writelog("value is "+val.toString());
    writelog("<br/>”);
...
```

At the line `val.toString()` the JS just stops. Anybody have a clue whats going on? The val will basically look something like the following.
undefined true true false 90 100 -1 -1 522 1 false 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Any errors reported in your console?

Comment: Well if `val` can be `undefined` (and this is what I understand from the end of your question...), you can't invoke `undefined.toString()`.

Comment: What is the specific error that is thrown by the parser ? It's likely that val is null or undefined causing a ReferenceError or TypeError to be thrown...

Answer (score 2):

Any time you want to work with values you should check to ensure they exist.

```
function SCOSetValue(nam,val){

    nam = (typeof nam !== "undefined") ? nam : "nam not defined";
    val = (typeof val !== "undefined") ? val : "val not defined";

    writelog("in SCOSetValue");
    writelog("name is "+nam.toString());
    writelog("value is "+val.toString());
    writelog("<br/>”);
```

Also, if you want to save yourself from having to write `toString()` all the time, just add `+ ""` to the variable. It coerces it to a string.

```
function SCOSetValue(nam,val){

    nam = (typeof nam !== "undefined") ? nam + "" : "nam not defined";
    val = (typeof val !== "undefined") ? val + "" : "val not defined";

    writelog("in SCOSetValue");
    writelog("name is "+nam);
    writelog("value is "+val);
    writelog("<br/>”);
```